# Asp Net Core timeouts

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to find out what configuration I've missed for timeouts in my Net Core WebApp. 
About 0.5% of requests are logged with 408 status code in App Insights. 
I've applied requestTimeout setting in web.config, and configured limit settings for Kestrel. Auto-scale is keeping CPU load below 70%.
Have I missed something in the configuration? I can't understand why these timeouts occur

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
 {
   options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 3221225472;
   options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate =
                       new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
  })
```

[image: Web.Config]

[image: App Insights]

[image: App Service plan]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, auto scale rule in azure web app has duration time as below images.

[image]

Azure web app track the metrics during the duration time.

e.g past 10 minutes exceed the 70%, it will scale, if not, it will not scale the app.

In my opinion, the reason why the request get 408 error is the azure web app still track the metrics  during the duration time. So in the duration time, it will not auto scale.

I suggest you could consider changing the auto scale rule threshold value and duration time to keep your web app always running well.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I'm sure that timeouts are not related to scale-outs cos I've experienced same issue using more powerful instances where CPU load was under 40%